# Resizing (increasing) primary OS partition

Tags: filesystems, ext4

I recently used Clonezilla to move from a very old HDD (160GB) to a new SSD (480gb). Clonezilla did a fine job but it left a lot of empty space unused. I made an attempt to extend the primary OS using GParted - but it didn't work. At this moment I don't have physical access to the server but I can remotely work on it (SSH). How would I go about increasing the primary partition size? This is how the partition table looks like at this moment:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 480.1 GB, 480103981056 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 58369 cylinders, total 937703088 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000cd8c5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   279676927   139837440   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       279678974   312578047    16449537    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda3       312578048   937701375   312561664   83  Linux
/dev/sda5       279678976   312578047    16449536   82  Linux swap / Solaris


df | grep -v tmpfs
Filesystem      1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev              8141076         12    8141064   1% /dev
/dev/sda1       137512016   80994792   49508968  63% /
none                    4          0          4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                 5120          0       5120   0% /run/lock
none              8151916        144    8151772   1% /run/shm
none               102400         32     102368   1% /run/user
```

Server running Ubuntu 14.04lts.

Comment: After you resize the partition, you will need to resize the filesystem using `resize2fs`.

Comment: There are two basic strategies, Either you resize the existing partitions or you create one or more new partitions. Creating a new one, perhaps for `/home` is simpler as you don't have physical access to the server. We need more information to be able to guide you further. Can you add the output of `df | grep -v tmpfs` to your question.

Comment: Updated with more info.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. So it looks like you are not using `/dev/sda3`. Can you run `mkdir /m ; mount -r /dev/sda3 /m ; ls /m ; umount /m ; rmdir /m` to check that you are not using anything in /m (/dev/sda3).

Comment: Thanks for your help I used GParted to delete swap and second partition and then increased the primary partition and created a new swap. worked out great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the swap partition in the middle of the drive. The good news is you have enough free space to make a swap file, so you don't have to go swapless:

```
(as root)
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap bs=1M count=8192
chmod 0000 /swap
mkswap /swap
swapon /swap
swapoff /dev/sda5
```

Now you can use the `fdisk` interface to reset the partition table and create a first partition, assigning blocks 2048 up to the rest of the disk to it. Commit these changes to disk. This should also reload the partition table. Check that `blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda1` returns the expected value, and then online resize the root partition with `resize2fs /dev/sda1`.

Comment: I will have physical access to the server tomorrow. Would you recommend (safer) doing it on premise with GParted - deleting swap and secondary partition and then increasing the primary partition + creating a new swap partition?

Comment: @bran I don't think there is much difference in safety, all of the tools `fdisk`, `resize2fs` and `gparted` have seen a lot of use.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried using GParted - since I was more familiar with it.